# Whats wrong with this transient? Not caching as expected

Tags: transient

I am trying to cache the returned data from a query using WP_Query.

It doesn't seem to be storing any where near the time I have specified. Sometimes its refreshing on every page load.

What might I be doing wrong?

```
<?php 
    // get our transient data if it exists
    // prevents pummelling the database with multiple random queries
    $tipsloop = get_transient ('homepage_tipsloop');
    if (!$tipsloop )
      {
       echo 'THIS IS NEW TRANSIENT DATA';
       $tipsloop = new WP_Query( array( 'cat' => '8', 'posts_per_page' => '1' , 'orderby' => 'rand') ); 
       set_transient ('homepage_tipsloop' , $tipsloop , MINUTE_IN_SECONDS * 5 ); // cached for 5 minutes
      }
?>

<!-- // Tips Loop -->
<?php while ($tipsloop->have_posts()) : $tipsloop->the_post(); 
    echo get_the_post_thumbnail($page->ID, 'homefooter-thumb'); ?>
      <div class="home-hotspots-tipscopy">
        <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>
<p>
      <a href="/category/tips/">MORE TIPS</a>
    </p>
<?php endwhile;  ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've change my comment into an answer. Please accept as solution. Change `set_transient ('homepage_tipsloop' , $tipsloop , MINUTE_IN_SECONDS * 5 );` to `set_transient ('homepage_tipsloop' , $tipsloop , 5 * MINUTE_IN_SECONDS );` as stated in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API#Using_Time_Constants)

Comment: Thanks i've switched it over. Seems to be working, not sure if its actually setting for 5 mins or not. Will have to do some testing

Comment: have you actually tried this out? the order doesn't matter, `60 * 5` and `5 * 60` are obviously the same result.

Comment: Yea, obviously would result the same. Seems to be caching appropriately now. I am on a WP Engine account. I went in and purged the cache, and made sure things were caching for around 5 minutes. Your correct, the order does not matter